# A word which is like 'manually' but means 'by eye' not 'by hand'?

Tags: word-choice

We make software for searching video and I am continuously explaining that this product 'avoids the need to watch video manually'. This grates with me because 'manually' means 'by hand' and you don't watch with your hands.

Is there a word which is the counterpart for 'manually' but means 'by eye'?

Comment: Intelligent video search tool that eliminates the need to *preview* video, perhaps?

Comment: Or *scan through the video,* or even just *watch the video*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a counterpart to *manually*, you could consider *optically* – but I think that word would be even less suitable in this case.

I have no problem with the word *manually* used in the context you describe. We do a lot of video editing where I work, and, yes, the process can be very *time consuming* and *labor intensive*. It may not be *manual labor* in the same sense that landscaping or auto assembly would be, but it could be construed as manual labor in the same sense that secretarial work might be – after all, we're paying someone to do it.

Furthermore, most video scanning *does* involve use the hands to a certain extent, even if it's only using a keyboard and mouse, or the controllers on a video player.

Incidentally, [Wikipedia's article on *manual labor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_labour) has some interesting points about the increasingly blurry lines between skilled and manual labor due to the advent of technology. It's worth reading more than a short excerpt, but I'll give this teaser [*emphasis added*]:

> Automation helps to bring mechanisation to more complicated tasks that require finer dexterity, **decision making based on visual input**, and a wider variety of intelligent movements.

Borrowing from that thought, you could say that your product helps *expedite or facilitate the complicated and time-consuming process of video editing*. From NOAD:

> **facilitate**: make (an action or process) easy or easier
> **expedite**: make (an action or process) happen sooner or be accomplished more quickly

By the way, isn't it interesting how the root of *expedite* is *ped* (meaning *foot*), yet we have no problem applying that word to processes that don't necessarily involve on-foot activities?

Comment: Plus, of course, there are many references to a [manual clutch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22manual+clutch%22&oq=%22manual+clutch%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.3594917&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on the Internet. I imagine the vast majority of them are actually operated by *foot*, not hand. In many contexts, *manual* just means *non-automatic*.